# Devise skip confirmation notification before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In Rails 4.2.0, I am using the Devise gem for authentication - `devise 3.4.1`.

The confirmation email is sent as soon as a user is created. We need to skip this confirmation email and send a custom email with the confirmation link. Please help me to solve this issue.

`:confirmable` is used in the User model.

Comment: You want to "skip" the email confirmation or you want to "change" the confirmation mail?

Answer (score 60):

You can try this

```
@user.skip_confirmation!
@user.save
```

Call `skip_confirmation!` before saving the user record.

To skip the confirmation notification only you can use `skip_confirmation_notification!`

```
@user.skip_confirmation_notification!
@user.save
```

Hope this helps!

---

**In Addition**

if you wish to skip confirmation on the same line without creating a variable and you do not need to confirm that particular User, for example in `seeds.rb`:

```
User.create(email: "#{role_name}@example.com",
            password: 'password',
            password_confirmation: 'password',
            confirmed_at: Time.now.utc, # skip confirmation)
```

**or**

If you just want to override the default email template, then you can run

```
rails generate devise:views -v registrations confirmations
```

It will generate the default views for confirmations then you can override it according to your need.

Comment: If I add `skip_confirmation!` then it will confirm the User account. But it should not work like this, a user should confirm their account through an email(custom email)

Comment: Ofcourse you can send custom email after skipping the devise confirmation email

Comment: Once user account is confirmed then what is the use of sending a custom mail with confirmation link?

Comment: To skip the confirmation email only you can use `.skip_confirmation_notification!` instead

Comment: If I use this email issue will get solve. But another issue will occur, If a user try to resend confirmation mail, in that mail confirmation link will throw an validation like "Confirmation token is invalid"

Comment: You are building your own mailer for confirmation, why would you allow user to use devise's confirmation again?

Comment: Yes. I am sending a welcome mail with a confirmation link when a user is created. Later they can be able to resend confirmation instructions(if account is not yet confirmed).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of disabling devise's in-build confirmation email and sending your custom email, you can customize devise's confirmation email.
You can generate devise view files using

```
rails generate devise:views
```

and then customize confirmation email.

Comment: this is the right answer. just override the view template!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

this can are the `UserController`

```
@user = User.new(email: "#{role_name}@example.com",
        password: 'password',
        password_confirmation: 'password',
        confirmed_at: Time.now.utc) # skip confirmation
@user.skip_confirmation!
@user.confirm
if @user.save
  MyMailer.confirmation(@user)
else
  # your implementation
end
```

See the doc https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer